# VBscsript "SET" question

Tags: vbscript

I know set in VBScript is used for assigning the object reference to the variable. I would like to only understand why its neccessary:

```
     Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
what about:
    dim fso
     fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") //would not it create the object directly and assign to the variable?
```

Thanks

Comment: They made it that way so that people could get easy rep points on SO every time somebody forgets to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think its just "because". The language is defined like this.
You need it in case of CreateObject and new of a Class.

So its the difference between a normal variable and an object.

The same reason why IsNothing, IsNull, ... exists.

Answer (score 0):

they are different. If you use `Dim` to assign a variable, that's just it, a variable. But if you use set , you are actually "initializing" an object reference to a variable so that you can then call the object's "methods" eg.

`Set objFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")`

Because now `objFS` is a reference, you can do things like

Create a folder using `objFS.CreateFolder`, or delete a folder: `objFS.DeleteFolder`. Check if a file exists using `objFS.FileExists` or get a file's extension using `objFS.GetExtensionName`, among other things.

the concept is much like instantiating a class and using its methods in languages like Java/Python etc.

Comment: Um, if the FSO is actual object, I should be able to do the same.
BTW, why did you write "objFS" instead of fso? I thought the methods will be fso.CreateFolder etc.< Thanks

Comment: objFS, FSO, it doesn't matter. as long as its a meaningful name. and yes, i have fixed the name.

Comment: Well, I understand the concept, just do not understand using of "set". In other languages you can assign reference just by =.
Class a=new class A();
RefA=a;